# Repository management and pod files:cocoapods

Tags: ios, repository, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods dependency manager in the iOS project.

The question is what is the proper way to manage the complete project in the repository [ mercurial]

Do I need to add all the cocoapods installed files into the repo?
Or is there a way to avoid all these files from adding repository?

What is the right way to manage the files?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly,

No, you should not commit your `pods/` folder.

source: the Cocoapods [example](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/.gitignore) project `.gitignore`

Im not sure on the specific details on how to ignore things in mercurial, but that `.gitignore` in the example is a safe guide on what should be ignored.